# How to convert "Mat >= int" statement from c++ to C#

Tags: c#, opencv

I've just started using OpenCVSharp and I'm trying to convert some of the OpenCV sample programs to C#. I'm not sure how to convert this line from *squares.cpp*:

`gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;`

This line gives the error

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Mat' and 'int'   OpenCVSharpTest

`gray` and `gray0` are both `Mat` instances. `l` and `N` are `int`.

Comment: Maybe [`Mat.GreaterThanOrEqual`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/25e3638b-8a70-a6e0-1f0a-0fe1c562e3d0.htm)?

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's a vectorized comparison with a scalar. Result should be another `Mat` with 0s and 255s representing false/true (which is basically a multi-dimensional array).

Comment: @DanMašek Good heavens. Does that mean the expression makes sense?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, it's thresholding an image -- doing `gray(x,y) = gray0(x,y) < ((l+1)*255/N) ? 255 : 0` for all (x,y) in the image. The right hand side of the comparison is to get several equally spaced threshold levels (it's in a loop).

Comment: An alternate solution would be to just use the [`Mat.Threshold`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/95e6d903-a97b-f190-4cfa-6de45361027f.htm) function.

Comment: @DanMašek Those both worked, thanks. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. This is my second day with OpenCVSharp so I'm still getting my bearings.

Comment: Yeah, the mapping of this C# port to the original C++ API doesn't seem very clear. I don't really use C# much, I just used my knowledge of the C++ API and searched the OpenCVSharp docs. I'll see if I can write up something decent.

Comment: Feel free to add some code examples to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's important to understand what the expression does.

```
cv::Mat gray0; // Somehow this is populated with a grayscale image
int N = 11;

for( int l = 1; l < N; l++ ) {
    cv::Mat gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;
    // more processing
}
```

The expression uses [`MatExpr operator>= (const Mat &a, double s)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#a908e8895c1daab24e5e8be7b9adddf12), which is a [matrix expression](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details) performing a vectorized comparison of a `Mat` with a scalar.

> Comparison: `A cmpop B`, `A cmpop alpha`, `alpha cmpop A`, where `cmpop` is one of `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `<`. The result of comparison is an 8-bit single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

Basically:

> ```
> for all (x,y) in the image:
>     threshold = (l + 1) * 255 / N
>     if (gray0(x,y) >= threshold):
>          gray(x,y) = 255
>     else
>          gray(x,y) = 0
> ```

This is basically a thresholding operation, it could easily be translated to use the [`cv::threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) function.

---

It seems that OpenCVSharp maps many of the C++ API operators into member functions of the `Mat` class. Specifically, [`Mat.GreaterThanOrEqual`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/25e3638b-8a70-a6e0-1f0a-0fe1c562e3d0.htm) seems to be a match to the operator used.

The alternative C++ function `cv::threshold` maps to [`Mat.Threshold`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/95e6d903-a97b-f190-4cfa-6de45361027f.htm). In this case you will need to use thresholding method `THRESH_BINARY`, and since it does `>` rather than `>=` you will need to offset the threshold appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try using 
 https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/cplusplus_to_csharp_converter_details.html

a free software for up to 100 lines of conversion.

Comment: That's not merely a conversion from c++ to c#. It's useless in this case.